# Extract description in site with no meta tag description?

Tags: php, extract, meta-tags

I need of a function in php  that extract a description of a site url that don't have meta tag description any idea?

i have tried this function but don't work :

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);

function getExcerpt($content) {
  $text = html_entity_decode($content);
  $excerpt = array();
  //match all tags
  preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)]+>|", $text, $p, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
  for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($p[0]); $x++) {
    if (preg_match('< p >i', $p[0][$x])) {
      $strip = strip_tags($p[0][$x]);
      if (preg_match("/\./", $strip))
        $excerpt[] = $strip;
    }
    if (isset($excerpt[0])){
      preg_match("/([^.]+.)/", $strip,$matches);
      return $matches[1];
    }
  }
  return false;
}

$excerpt = getExcerpt($content);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What do you mean by "extract a description?"

Comment: @Pekka I guess he's trying to take a relevant snippet of text from a page without a meta description.

Comment: yes if site don't have a meta tag description and i want however extract some text  for describe it

Comment: Define "don't work". If the code "don't work", then it is broken and doesn't represent what you are trying to do, and thus we cannot gather what you are trying to do by reading it.

Comment: don't work because i don't get any word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parsing HTML with RegEx](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) is almost always a bad idea.  Thankfully PHP has libraries that can do the work for you.  The following code uses DOMDocument to extract either the meta description or if one does not exist, the first 1000 characters in the page.

```
<?php
function getExcerpt($html) {

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    // Parse the inputted HTML into a DOM
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $metaTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    // Check for a meta description and return it if it exists
    foreach ($metaTags as $metaTag) {
        if ($metaTag->getAttribute('name') === "description") {
            return $metaTag->getAttribute('content');
        }
    }

    // No meta description, extract an excerpt from the body
    // Get the body node
    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
    $body = $body->item(0);

    // extract the contents
    $bodyText = $body->textContent;

    // collapse any line breaks
    $bodyText = preg_replace('/\s*\n\s*/', "\n", $bodyText);
    // collapse any more leftover spaces or tabs to single spaces
    $bodyText = preg_replace('/[    ]+/', ' ', $bodyText);

    // return the first 1000 chars
    return trim(substr($bodyText, 0, 1000));

}

$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

echo nl2br(getExcerpt($html));
```

You'll probably want to add a little more logic to it, some DOM traversal to try to find the content, or just some snippet near the middle of the text.  As it is, this code will probably grab a bunch of unwanted stuff like the top of the page navigation etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if there is meta description available, if yes then display that else search for the `<p>` tags and display that data as description (you might want to put a limit on length of a paragraph, e.g. if length is less than 30, search for next paragraph). If there is no `<p>` tag then simply display the title as description (that's how facebook and Digg works)